# Can't access NAS from from subnet 1 but works in subnet 2. How to solve?

Tags: networking, router, ip, nas, subnet

The topology is represented on the attachment. Routers are both Huawei HG9146V and HG8247H. Two subnets with DHCP running on R.TR for 1st subnet and static assigned addresses in 2nd.

The NAS (192.168.1.100) is placed in 2nd subnet and can be reached from 2nd only. How to make it available for both subnets?

I have tried adding allowed list of IP addresses for NAS and checked settings of Windows Firewall (SMB-In). Anyway there's nothing.

[image: Topology]

Two switches are placed in access layer are unmanaged devices 24 ports each.

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that you have both 192.168.1/24 and 192.168.2/24 networks coexisting on the same ethernet?

Comment: This is understood correctly. Coexisting networks

Answer (score 2):

Currently none of the devices *know* where the other subnet is. Client devices send packets to their gateway, and the gateway just forwards them to its ISP based on the default route.

To make this work, each router needs a static route for the opposite subnet. Since both subnets share the same Ethernet broadcast domain, the routes do not need to specify a gateway – only the correct interface.

- R.T needs a route for 192.168.1.0/24 dev LAN (no gateway),
- R.TR needs a route for 192.168.2.0/24 dev LAN (no gateway).

Note that this will still cause all traffic to go through the router and back – the advantage is that it can be filtered by the router's ACLs, the disadvantage is that it might not achieve the same performance as switching.

Alternatively, you could add the routes to each individual device. With some clients (at least Windows and dhclient) this can be automated by using DHCP option 121 ("Classless static routes"), with others you'll have to do it manually.

This will let devices communicate with the NAS directly through only the switch, without having to bounce off the router, at the cost of much manual configuration.

Comment: On this HG9146V router there's no menu with static route. HG8247H router can provide a static route. I will try this. Thanks for mentioning that sir.
Also DHCP will be provided with the option. And a good idea to add routes. There are not so many devices that desired to use NAS. Appreciate. I will try to apply this.

Comment: It does. I have got a trick. Now trying in static routing. Appreciate

Comment: If nothing else works, you _could_ use router-based routes in one direction and client-based routes in the other direction. (For example, client→router→NAS but NAS→client.) This will require the router's firewall to unconditionally allow _all_ packets to/from the NAS, even those which are "invalid".

Comment: 1_INTERNET_R_VID_10 is only available for R.T only, not br0 that should be as I understood.
Also Firewall seems like a common level configuration without options. Not so extended menu. I wish I resolve this problem
Thanks for the ideas and choices

Comment: I can't deal with static routing due to a wacky firmware version. It seems like impossibly to perform it correctly. I am going to request ISP for replacing routers or updating firmware. This is disaster.
Appreciate your assistance